# Using T-SQL to create Dynamic Pagination

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I developed a stored procedure shown below to create pagination where each unique combination of `SLARID, FundName, DeptName, Title` generates a report page number in consecutive order, where each of the above sections (defined by a unique combination of `SLARID, FundName, DeptName, Title`) take only two pages.

Below is the code I came up with as well as the result set. As you can see in the result set, each unique combination occurs ever two pages.  However, I now find that some of the records in the report are greater than two pages. For example, SLARID 621 now encompasses three pages instead of two. That means that SLARID 610 should start on Report Page 18 since SLARID 621 now uses pages 15,16,17.I would like to get some ideas on how to approach this problem

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spADT_GenerateSLAR_Pagination]
    (@Response VARCHAR(255) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY

        DELETE FROM dbo.tblADT_SLARPageIndex

        INSERT INTO dbo.tblADT_SLARPageIndex (SLARID, Fund, FundName , DeptNumber, DeptName, Title, RowNumber, ReportPageNumber)
            SELECT  
                S.SLARID, VW.[Fund], vw.[Fund Name],  
                vw.Dept, vw.DeptName, A.Title,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vw.[Fund Name], vw.DeptName, A.Title, S.Slarid) AS RowNumber,       
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vw.[Fund Name], vw.DeptName, A.Title, S.Slarid) + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY vw.[Fund Name], vw.DeptName, A.Title, S.SLARID) - 1) AS ReportPageNumber 
                --ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY vw.[Fund Name], vw.DeptName, a.Title)  AS RowNumber
            FROM 
                tblADT_SLAR S 
            LEFT JOIN 
                tblADT_Amend A ON S.ADT_Amend_SuppID = A.SuppID 
            LEFT JOIN 
                vwAmendUnionSum VW ON A.SuppID = vw.SuppID
            WHERE   
                A.[Group] = 3 
                AND a.CMO_ReviewStatus = 1 
                AND A.Process = (SELECT MAX(Process) FROM tblADT_Amend)
            GROUP BY
                S.SLARID, VW.[Fund], vw.[Fund Name],
                vw.Dept, vw.DeptName, A.Title
            ORDER BY 
                vw.[Fund Name], vw.DeptName, A.Title

        COMMIT TRAN

        SELECT @Response = 'SLAR Page Index generation succeeded'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRAN

        SELECT @Response = 'SLAR Page Index generation failed'
    END CATCH;
```

Below is the result set

[image]

Comment: Thinking about it, I think I need to determine how many rows does a specific combination of SLARID, FundName, Dept, and title take and how many rows are in a piece of 81/2 x 11 paper

Comment: We don't really have an idea what result you are trying to get. Perhaps [Keyset pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) might work for you. Upside: much more performant and you can jump to a particular key, downside: you can't jump to a particular page number, you need to know a key (or have the last one from the previous query). By the way: `A.Process = (SELECT MAX(Process) FROM tblADT_Amend)` looks like it could do with a window function. Also, better formatting would help

Comment: Your idea about using keyset pagination is very intriguing. As a matter of fact, I was thinking about using offset but I don't think it would work in this situation

Comment: As a clarification, I am trying to create a table of contents page in a summary report that references the page number of the detail report

Comment: Sounds like something that should really be done in the application. But keyset could work for you here because you don't need to know the page number, you just want to jump to a certain key